# How to customize custom content elements to work for fluid typo3 6 -> 9

Tags: typo3

What is the easiest way to change custom content elements that were created for a Typo3 6 site to a working custom content element for Typo3 9?

Comment: Were they created for `Css styled content` or `Fluid styled content`?

Comment: I am not sure but I think they are made for CSS Styled Content as there is no fluid template in the extension folder (of the content elements)

Comment: Please show the code. There are myriads of ways to create custom content elements.